# React rerenders 4 times when calling setState after pointermove?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a bug where calling a single setState causes a component to rerender 4 times (2 times with strict mode off) under a specific scenario.

I'm calling setState when a swipe gesture begins. The state causes a React.lazy component to render.

```
const Content = React.lazy(async () => import(''));

...

const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(false);
console.log('render'); // called 4 times

...

elem.on('pointermove', () => {
  if (isFirstMove) {
    setShowContent(true);
    console.log('first pointermove'); // called once
  }
});

...

<Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
  {showContent && <Content />}
</Suspense>
```

I checked that `setShowContent` is only called once. This bug goes away if I do any of the following:

- change "pointermove" to "click", "touchstart", etc
- change React.lazy + import() to a normal import

It seems like the combination of a pointermove event handler and React.lazy causes this bug. I can't figure out a minimal reproducible example. The pointermove handler is defined in `@use-gesture`, a library for handling gesture.

I think this might have something to do with concurrent mode? Maybe while React is attempting to rerender, it detects that there's another pointermove event with a handler, so it interrupts the rerender. Is there a better explanation?

Comment: Is there any reason you use `elem.on('pointermove', callback)` instead of `<Component onPointerMove={callback}>`?

Comment: It's from the @use-gesture library

Comment: What's the bug? The amount of times something renders is an implementation detail. If you're experiencing a logical error, something else might be wrong. If there's no performance problems, then who cares about how many times it renders? What's the actual bug?